# Where to get Microsoft SQL Management Studio when using Amazon RDS SQL servers?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, amazon-rds

My company is interested in using Amazon's RDS service for our Microsoft SQL Server Web Edition. However, we are a bit confused on how to actually connect to the database to initialize it.

In the Amazon [Getting Started Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html) it simply says "2. Run Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio". Where would I obtain this management studio if the reason I am using Amazon RDS is to avoid buying a SQL Server license in the first place? Are there other programs that can do the same?

The connection settings from there seems very straight forward, but we're left looking for the actual software to connect.

Comment: Did you look for the free version MS offers for SQL Express?

Comment: I did, but it only allows SQL Express features and has nothing where I can use the SQL Web Server features

Comment: Developer Edition can be had for as cheap as $40. If you wait for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1, the free version of Management Studio that ships with that version will be fully functional, not stripped down like previous editions ([read more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2012/09/24/announcing-microsoft-sql-server-2012-service-pack-1-sp1-community-technology-preview-4-ctp4.aspx)). And yes, you can manage down-level versions (2005, 2008, 2008 R2) in addition to 2012, so no reason to use older versions of the tool.

Comment: Sorry, an addendum - you want to download Express with Tools or Express with Advanced Services, not just Express stand-alone, in order to get Management Studio Express.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio is only available with a Sql Server Licence.  You could get a copy of Sql Developer Edition.  That also has Management Studio and is much cheaper.